# How to configure telegraf to send a folder-size to influxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I am having a hard time understanding and using the [`disk`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/system/DISK_README.md) plugin.

I want to emit the `folder size` for `/var/lib/influxdb/hh/`, and I am trying to figure out how to wire this using the `disk` plugin.

I have tried the following :

- setup a new configuration file for telegraf here `vi /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/influxdbdata_telegraf.conf`
- added this configuration 

  `[[inputs.disk]]
  mount_points = ["/var/lib/influxdb/hh/"]`
- now I try to query the data from influxDB, and I don't see this. But I see the other measurements.

I am definitely confused with the usage of `disk` plugin. I can write an exec plugin and finish it. But wanted to hold off and try to get this working with an existing plugin. (*I am pretty sure this would be in some plugin, which I am missing*)

Comment: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/system/DISK_README.md the doc says "mount points" is your `/var/lib/influxdb/hh/` a mount point or a directory ?

Comment: its a directory, and this is something i am trying to figure out.

Comment: looks like there is no way to achieve this, asides writing your own script and wiring it into `exec` section.