# How to monitor the size of a directory via Telegraf

Tags: du, telegraf

We need to monitor the size of a directory (for example the data directory of InfluxDB) to set up alerts in Grafana. As mentioned here: [How to configure telegraf to send a folder-size to influxDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44273430/2759336) , there is no built-in plugin for this.

We don't mind using the `inputs.exec` section of Telegraf. The directories are not huge (low filecount + dircount), so deep scanning (like the use of `du`) is fine by us.

One of the directories we need to monitor is `/var/lib/influxdb/data`.

What would be a simple script to execute, and what are the caveats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible natively with [filecount](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/filecount) plugin

```
[[inputs.filecount]]
directories = ["/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data"]
```

Output:

```
> filecount,directory=/var/lib/influxdb/engine/data,host=psg count=424i,size_bytes=387980393i 1652195855000000000
```

Comment: Great, that seems to be the only good answer as of current. I switched my answer flag.

Answer (score 11):

You could create a simple bash script `metrics-exec_du.sh` with the following content (chmod 755):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
du -bs "${1}" | awk '{print "[ { \"bytes\": "$1", \"dudir\": \""$2"\" } ]";}'
```

And activate it by putting the following in the Telegraf config file:

`[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = [ "YOUR_PATH/metrics-exec_du.sh /var/lib/influxdb/data" ]
  timeout = "5s"
  name_override = "du"
  name_suffix = ""
  data_format = "json"
  tag_keys = [ "dudir" ]`

Caveats:

1. The `du` command can stress your server, so use with care
2. The user `telegraf` must be able to scan the dirs. There are several options, but since InfluxDB's directory mask is a bit unspecified (see: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5171#issuecomment-306419800), we applied a rather crude workaround (examples are for `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`):

   - Add the `influxdb` group to the user `telegraf` : `sudo usermod --groups influxdb --append telegraf`
   - Put the following in the crontab, run for example each 10 minutes: `10 * * * * chmod -R g+rX /var/lib/influxdb/data > /var/log/influxdb/chmodfix.log 2>&1`

Result, configured in Grafana (data source: InfluxDB):
[image: Grafana dirsize monitoring]

Cheers, TW

Comment: Hi Tw Bert. I am trying to do something similar to this but with telegraf and influxdb running in containers. Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77085192/how-to-set-permissions-to-be-able-to-monitor-influxdb-data-and-wal-directory  Do you know a way to fix the permissions properly? It seems a little clunky to periodically change permissions. Any suggestion would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you need to monitor multiple directories I updated the answer by [Tw Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2759336/tw-bert) and extended it to allow you to pass them all on one command line.  This saves you having to add multiple `[[input.exec]]` entries into your telegraf.conf file.

Create the file `/etc/telegraf/scripts/disk-usage.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "["
du -ks "$@" | awk '{if (NR!=1) {printf ",\n"};printf "  { \"directory_size_kilobytes\": "$1", \"path\": \""$2"\" }";}'
echo
echo "]"
```

I want to monitor two directories: `/mnt/user/appdata/influxdb` and `/mnt/user/appdata/grafana`.  I can do something like this:

```
# Get disk usage for multiple directories
[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = [ "/etc/telegraf/scripts/disk-usage.sh /mnt/user/appdata/influxdb /mnt/user/appdata/grafana" ]
  timeout = "5s"
  name_override = "du"
  name_suffix = ""
  data_format = "json"
  tag_keys = [ "path" ]
```

Once you've updated your config, you can test this with:

```
telegraf --debug --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf --input-filter exec --test
```

Which should show you what Telegraf will push to influx:

```
bash-4.3# telegraf --debug --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf --input-filter exec --test
> du,host=SomeHost,path=/mnt/user/appdata/influxdb directory_size_kilobytes=80928 1536297559000000000
> du,host=SomeHost,path=/mnt/user/appdata/grafana directory_size_kilobytes=596 1536297559000000000
```

Comment: You better use `"$@"` though with `du`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053064/difference-between-and

Answer (score 1):

The solutions already provided look good to me and highlighting the caveats such a read permission is great. An alternative worth mentioning is Using Telegraf to collect the data as proposed in [monitor diskspace on influxdb with telegraf](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/914).

```
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["udp://your_host:8089"]
  database = "telegraf_metrics"

  ## Retention policy to write to. Empty string writes to the default rp.
  retention_policy = ""
  ## Write consistency (clusters only), can be: "any", "one", "quorum", "all"
  write_consistency = "any"

  ## Write timeout (for the InfluxDB client), formatted as a string.
  ## If not provided, will default to 5s. 0s means no timeout (not recommended).
  timeout = "5s" 

# Read metrics about disk usage by mount point
[[inputs.disk]]
  ## By default, telegraf gather stats for all mountpoints.
  ## Setting mountpoints will restrict the stats to the specified mountpoints.
  # mount_points = ["/"]

  ## Ignore some mountpoints by filesystem type. For example (dev)tmpfs (usually
  ## present on /run, /var/run, /dev/shm or /dev).
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs"]
```

**Note:** the timeout should be considered carefully. Maybe hourly readings would be sufficient to avoid exhaustion by logging.

Comment: Just skimming this, but I think this is `df` vs `du` . Different stats. Good to mention the alternative tho.