# How to monitor the size of a mounted directory via Telegraf docker container?

Tags: docker, influxdb, mount, telegraf, du

I am not particularly fluent with linux, so would appreciate some help.

My system is running with an external drive mounted at `/mnt/SSD_240GB` and contains two directories that I am trying to monitor the size of, with Telegraf and InfluxDB. These directories are:

`/mnt/SSD_240GB/docker_data/InfluxDB/data`
and

`/mnt/SSD_240GB/docker_data/InfluxDB/wal`

Telegraf and InfluxDB are both running in seperate docker containers.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44386280), I have made a shell script which contains the following code, which just uses `du` to get the sizes of any directories that you pass in as arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "["
du -s -B1 "$@" | awk '{if (NR!=1) {printf ",\n"};printf "  { \"dir_size_bytes\": "$1", \"path\": \""$2"\" }";}'
echo
echo "]"
```

Running this script directly inside the Telegraf container works as expected, giving the correct file sizes :
[image]

Now I try to get Telegraf to automatically run this script at regular intervals by using the [exec](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/exec) plugin, by adding the following code to my telegraf.conf file:

```
[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = [ "/etc/telegraf/scripts/get_disk_usage.sh /mnt/SSD_240GB/docker_data/InfluxDB/wal /mnt/SSD_240GB/docker_data/InfluxDB/data" ]
  timeout = "1m"
  name_override = "du"
  name_suffix = ""
  data_format = "json"
  tag_keys = [ "path" ]
```

The problem is that now the data which arrives in InfluxDB does not match this. In fact the file sizes returned are always the same (20480 bytes and 4096 bytes, respectively):
[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks!

---

Here is the telegraf section of the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
  telegraf:
    image: telegraf
    container_name: telegraf_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8125:8125
    networks:
      - docker_monitoring_network
    volumes:
      - /mnt/SSD_240GB/docker_config_files/Telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
      - /mnt/SSD_240GB/docker_config_files/Telegraf/scripts:/etc/telegraf/scripts
      - /mnt/SSD_240GB:/mnt/SSD_240GB:ro
```